# Use Baldur's Gate 2 save in the Enhanced Edition

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

Is it possible to use a save game from BG2: SoA in the Enhanced Edition? I've been playing the gog.com version of BG2 and I would like to take advantage of the nice new rendered backgrounds. However, I'm in Act 3 and I would rather not have to restart.